# CkEditor 4 [error status: 500] After Uploading File to Server

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, ckeditor4

I am using Asp.NET Core 6 & CKEditor 4

When I click on send button to upload selected image from local path, file uploads successfully but after that error appears as follow:

> HTTP error occurred during file upload (error status: 500).

I added extra directory to application root and used StaticFile like bellow:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()

    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FilesCKEditor")),
        RequestPath = "/FilesCKEditor"
    });
```

Everything is ok when uploading image to the server but return status never send to ckEditor image browser dialog.

Please help me.

Thank You All

Comment: there may many reason for 500 error, could you see the detailed information?

Comment: So, how can I inspect this issue. Image save to server successfully and in HTML img tag, I can show image from this location but, CKEditor probably cannot access to this location. By the way, I tested TinyMc as well and this plugin throw status code 500 after uploading image to server.

Comment: As a final solution I changed directory permission to "Everyone" but, new solution didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe you could try with ContentRootPath as this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root

Comment: Thank you, but error exist as well.